# Bash Cannot assign requested address

Tags: bash, variables

I'm trying to execute a command when systemd start, till here no problem but the command is not executed like expected.

This's the part of code that won't work like I want:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

############ CONFIGURATION ############
OWRT_UNAME="root" # username to connect to openwrt
# for the ssh password generate a key pair
OWRT_IP_ADDR="10.0.0.1" # Router address to connect
            #############
QBITTORRENT_HOST="localhost" # qbittorrent machine?
QBITTORRENT_USERNAME="admin" # Username for qbittorrent remote machine
QBITTORRENT_PASSWORD="adminadmin" # Password for qbittorrent remote machine
QBITTORRENT_PORT="8081" # Port for qbittorrent webui
############ CONFIGURATION ############

LOG_ENABLE=0
LOG_PATH="/tmp"

if [[ $LOG_ENABLE == 1 ]]; then
    if [[ ! -d $LOG_PATH ]]; then
        mkdir $LOG_PATH
    fi

    if [[ ! -w "$LOG_PATH/${0##*/}.log" ]]; then
        touch "$LOG_PATH/${0##*/}.log"
    fi
fi

[[ $LOG_ENABLE == 1 ]] && echo "########## $(date) ##########" >> "$LOG_PATH/${0##*/}.log"

QBT_BIN="$(command -v qbt)"
SSH_BIN="$(command -v ssh)"
JQ_BIN="$(command -v jq)"

if [[ -z "$QBT_BIN" ]]; then # If no qbt found
    [[ "$LOG_ENABLE" == "1" ]] && echo "Error, no qbt found, please install it from https://github.com/fedarovich/qbittorrent-cli" >> "$LOG_PATH/${0##*/}.log"
    exist
fi

if [[ -z "$SSH_BIN" ]]; then # If no qbt found
    [[ $LOG_ENABLE == 1 ]] && echo "Error, no ssh found, please install it" >> "$LOG_PATH/${0##*/}.log"
    exist
fi

REMOTE_PIA_PORT=$($SSH_BIN $OWRT_UNAME@$OWRT_IP_ADDR 'cat /tmp/pia-port-forward')

if [[ -n $REMOTE_PIA_PORT ]]; then # I get the pia port
    #ACTUAL_QBITTORRENT_PORT=$($QBT_BIN server settings connection --username "$QBITTORRENT_USERNAME" --password "$QBITTORRENT_PASSWORD" --url "http://${QBITTORRENT_HOST}:$QBITTORRENT_PORT" | awk '{print $9}') # get the actual qBittorrent port
    ACTUAL_QBITTORRENT_PORT=$($QBT_BIN server settings connection --username "$QBITTORRENT_USERNAME" --password "$QBITTORRENT_PASSWORD" --url "http://${QBITTORRENT_HOST}:$QBITTORRENT_PORT" --format json | $JQ_BIN '.ListenPort') # get the actual qBittorrent port

    if [[ $ACTUAL_QBITTORRENT_PORT == $REMOTE_PIA_PORT ]]; then # pia port is the same that that the qBittorrent port
        [[ $LOG_ENABLE == 1 ]] && echo "qBittorrent port is already the good one, nothing to do, see you later!" >> "$LOG_PATH/${0##*/}.log"
    else # qBittorrent use a different port
        [[ $LOG_ENABLE == 1 ]] && echo "qBittorrent port is not the right one, I'll change it" >> "$LOG_PATH/${0##*/}.log"
        sleep 1
        $QBT_BIN server settings connection -p "$REMOTE_PIA_PORT" --username "$QBITTORRENT_USERNAME" --password "$QBITTORRENT_PASSWORD" --url "http://${QBITTORRENT_HOST}:$QBITTORRENT_PORT"
        sleep 1
    fi
else # I can't find the pia port
    [[ $LOG_ENABLE == 1 ]] && echo "I can't find the PIA port from $PIA_EXT_PORT make sure that exist and is reachable" >> "$LOG_PATH/${0##*/}.log"
fi
```

If I execute this command on putty session I've no problem

```
+ OWRT_UNAME=root
+ OWRT_IP_ADDR=10.0.0.1
+ QBITTORRENT_HOST=localhost
+ QBITTORRENT_USERNAME=admin
+ QBITTORRENT_PASSWORD=adminadmin
+ QBITTORRENT_PORT=8081
+ LOG_ENABLE=0
+ LOG_PATH=/tmp
+ [[ 0 == 1 ]]
+ [[ 0 == 1 ]]
++ command -v qbt
+ QBT_BIN=/usr/bin/qbt
++ command -v ssh
+ SSH_BIN=/usr/bin/ssh
++ command -v jq
+ JQ_BIN=/usr/bin/jq
+ [[ -z /usr/bin/qbt ]]
+ [[ -z /usr/bin/ssh ]]
++ /usr/bin/ssh root@10.0.0.1 'cat /tmp/pia-port-forward'
+ REMOTE_PIA_PORT=46786
+ [[ -n 46786 ]]
++ /usr/bin/qbt server settings connection --username admin --password adminadmin --url http://localhost:8081 --format json
++ /usr/bin/jq .ListenPort
+ ACTUAL_QBITTORRENT_PORT=46786
+ [[ 46786 == 46786 ]]
+ [[ 0 == 1 ]]
```

But If I restart the service and the script is triggered, I see this

```
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + OWRT_UNAME=root
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + OWRT_IP_ADDR=10.0.0.1
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + QBITTORRENT_HOST=localhost
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + QBITTORRENT_USERNAME=admin
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + QBITTORRENT_PASSWORD=adminadmin
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + QBITTORRENT_PORT=8081
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + LOG_ENABLE=0
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + LOG_PATH=/tmp
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + [[ 0 == 1 ]]
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: ++ command -v qbt
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + QBT_BIN=/usr/bin/qbt
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: ++ command -v ssh
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + SSH_BIN=/usr/bin/ssh
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: ++ command -v jq
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + JQ_BIN=/usr/bin/jq
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + [[ -z /usr/bin/qbt ]]
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + [[ -z /usr/bin/ssh ]]
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: ++ /usr/bin/ssh root@10.0.0.1 'cat /tmp/pia-port-forward'
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + REMOTE_PIA_PORT=46786
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + [[ -n 46786 ]]
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: ++ /usr/bin/qbt server settings connection --username admin --password adminadmin --url http://localhost:8081 --format json
Mar 14 16:04:30 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: ++ /usr/bin/jq .ListenPort
Mar 14 16:04:33 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: Cannot assign requested address
Mar 14 16:04:33 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + ACTUAL_QBITTORRENT_PORT=
Mar 14 16:04:33 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + [[ '' == 46786 ]]
Mar 14 16:04:33 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + [[ 0 == 1 ]]
Mar 14 16:04:33 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + sleep 1
Mar 14 16:04:34 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: + /usr/bin/qbt server settings connection -p 46786 --username admin --password adminadmin --url http://localhost:8081
Mar 14 16:04:36 Qnap qBittorrent_OPENWRT_Pia_Port.sh[27486]: Cannot assign requested address
```

I can't understand why I get this error and the ACTUAL_QBITTORRENT_PORT is not assigned correctly.
I'm not a programmer, so I made this little script with my own knowing and some research, maybe there's a better way to make it, especially the jq part, maybe there's a better way to parse json data (can be a list too) but is another story, now I've to fix this little problem.

Any idea?

Comment: That's almost certainly written by qbt, not bash. Keep in mind that when you run a pipeline, all the commands are run at the same time, so whether the `Cannot assign requested address` comes under `qbt` or `jq` is meaningless.

Comment: BTW, `QBT_BIN=$(command -v qbt)` is not a good practice. bash itself caches executable locations, and the cost of forking off a subshell costs more than populating that cache does. Just use `qbt` instead of a variable wrapping that name.

Comment: Anyhow, the program whose execution you need to trace is `qbt`, not bash, I'd suggest using `strace` to do so, and looking particularly closely at `bind()` and `socket()` calls, and comparing the ports it's trying to use against ones that `sudo netstat --listen -nep` says are already in use.

Comment: I also tried with awk, so maybe is qbt that make this error. Do you know some other way to populate the variable? Or do you have some idea about why if I use the command inside putty works but inside script won't?

Comment: Since the error depends on which port numbers are *already in use*, it's going to behave differently depending on what other software is running on the system at the same time. For example, could the qbt server you started in putty still be running? Use `netstat` to check, as described above.

Comment: It's only a one_time script, that run before start qbittorrent, to be sure that the port is the right one, on other side there's a router that handle all the situation for the port-forward.

Comment: Once again, check the syscalls. Once you use `strace` to know which specific operation qbt is asking the OS to perform on its behalf that fails, you can use `netstat` to ask the OS's network stack to get details on *why* it fails. Anything else is guesswork.

Comment: As for why some execution contexts succeed and others fail, we want to nail down the failure before we speculate. For all I know, maybe your script is invoked in a SELinux context that doesn't allow outbound network connections at all; there are too many things that can go wrong to make it worth speculating without collecting more details first. Either way, it's certainly not a bash-specific problem; the bash code does no bind operations at all, so it couldn't possibly get a failure trying to bind to a port.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. I think I've to strace inside the script, because in all other way it works. Right? I'll do some search to better understand how to strace this situation

Comment: `actual_qbittorrent_port=$(strace -f -o /tmp/mylog.strace qbt server ... | jq ...)` -- btw, the switch to lowercase variable names is in accordance with POSIX specifications; all-caps names are reserved for variables that are either set by the shell itself or ones that modify behavior of the shell and/or other POSIX-specific tools, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are guaranteed safe for applications to use without modifying behavior of POSIX tools.

Comment: (on that aside, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable; to quote the relevant lines: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.*)

Comment: ...anyhow, the above will write to `/tmp/mylog.strace` which you can read through at your leisure. Also, if it *is* qbt writing the error message, you'll see that write operation happening in the strace log.